# Can gstreamer play rtsp mpeg2 stream encrypted by vlc?

Tags: stream, gstreamer, rtsp, vlc, encryption

I have an encrypted mpeg2 stream, e.g. rtsp://10.91.1.13:8554/enc.ts
produced by vlc.
With vlc I can decrypt it with ts-csa-ck= option 
and thus play.

Is there any possibility to play such encrypted streams using gstreamer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No AFAIK. There is no plugin to do this directly for you. You will have to write your own plugin to do the decryption.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a long time ago, but FWIW now you can by appending an 's' to the protocol (as in secure). For example:

```
rtsps://10.91.1.13:8554/enc.ts
```